# Is there a way to do search and replace inside of a bash command in your command history?

Tags: bash, command-history

Say for instance I have the following in my command line history:

```
systemctl status puppet.service
```

And I want to re-execute it with `status` changed to `start`:

```
systemctl start puppet.service
```

Is there a way I can `%s/tus/art/g` with keyboard shortcuts or something?

Comment: Would opening the current line up in an editor help you? `Esc+v` in vi-mode, and `Ctrl+x`+`Ctrl+e` in emacs-mode.  It would use the editor from `$VISUAL`.

Comment: Is it worth the effort? With `ctrl+←` twice, `ctrl+w` you delete the word "status", then type "start".

Comment: define an alias if you do this more often is your best choice ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retype the last command with this shortcut:

```
!!
```

Then you can do inplace substitution with :

```
:s/from/to
```

Put it all together become :

```
!!:s/from/to/
```

Previously digited command can be referenced with `!-n` and the substitution occurs as well:

```
!-1:s/from/to/
```

If you want to refer to a command with a string another shortcut that would be usefull:

```
!?cmd?:s/from/to
```

which in you case become :

```
!?systemctl?:s/tus/art/g
```

Comment: This does not work on what's typed on the current command line, but on lines available through the command line history. That means that you have to have executed the command at least once to be able to recall it and modify it.

Comment: Yes. My fault. I have missunderstood the question.

Comment: Well, the fact that the answer was accepted leads me to believe that the user didn't really know what they were asking for.

Comment: @Kusalananda I changed the question title to make it more relevant to the answer.

Comment: @mondo-cane Also, `^status^start^` would do the same as `!!:s/status/start/` (the manual calls this "quick substitution"). Note that this affects only the most recent command in the history.